# Roslaunch - Include file remotely

Tags: launch, ros

I am trying to launch a file from remote computer but I could not success. Actually I can connect to remote computer but I think the problem is with including a file from remote computer. In other words, I am looking for a machine tag for include. Here is the my code:

```
<launch>  

    <group >
      <machine name="marvin-1" address="tek-marvin-1" user="blabla" password="blabla" env-loader="/home/blabla/.rosLaunchScript.sh"/>  

      <include file="$(find openni_launch_marvin)/launch/kinect_left.launch"/>
    </group>     

</launch>
```

Answer (score 2):

roslaunch evaluates everything on the local machine before remotely executing it.

Untargeted ticket here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/280